# definition of $e^H$ in MUSIC algorithms

Tags: complex-analysis, matrices, time-series

i would like to clarify what does represent $e^H$ in the formula

[image]

where

[image]

as i know  definition of  $e^H$  is hermitian,which means that it's complex conjugate equal original  variable  with changed  sign.it the same  happens  here?$e$  as i know represents also eigenvector of  autocorrelation matrix.please help me to clarify it .link for MUSIC algorithm is there 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_signal_classification

Comment: Given that $e$ is a vector, $e^H$ is probably its [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose).

Comment: ok thanks for reply